# Using pure html and css to produce a email carousel inconsistent in outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook

I am working on a carousel with 3 images included for an email. For the output, I want it to present 1 image at a time with 3 dots that toggle through each image.

Due to the constraint of emails not being compatible with Javascript. I have to stick to html and css. Please see code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Slider</title>
<style>
    .slider-holder
    {
        width: 560px;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: yellow;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 0px;
        text-align: center;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .image-holder
    {
        width: 2400px;
        background-color: black;
        height: 400px;
        clear: both;
        position: relative;

        -webkit-transition: left 2s;
        -moz-transition: left 2s;
        -o-transition: left 2s;
        transition: left 2s;
    }

    .slider-image
    {
        float: left;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #slider-image-1:target ~ .image-holder
    {
        left: 0px;
    }

    #slider-image-2:target ~ .image-holder
    {
        left: -800px;
    }

    #slider-image-3:target ~ .image-holder
    {
        left: -1600px;
    }

    .button-holder
    {
        position: relative;
        top: -20px;
    }

    .slider-change
    {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: brown;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="slider-holder">
    <span id="slider-image-1"></span>
    <span id="slider-image-2"></span>
    <span id="slider-image-3"></span>
    <div class="image-holder">
        <img src="rsz_test.jpg" class="slider-image" />
        <img src="rsz_1test.jpg" class="slider-image" />
        <img src="rsz_test.jpg" class="slider-image" />
    </div>
    <div class="button-holder">
        <a href="#slider-image-1" class="slider-change"></a>
        <a href="#slider-image-2" class="slider-change"></a>
        <a href="#slider-image-3" class="slider-change"></a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem comes when I send it to outlook email addresses. The output tends to show all the images at once. *I have taken out the doctype*

Truly appreciated to anyone that has any pointers in keeping it consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot test this, but I ran  your code through Premailer, an email inliner tool. Try it!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Slider</title>

</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
#slider-image-1:target ~ .image-holder {
left: 0px;
}
#slider-image-2:target ~ .image-holder {
left: -800px;
}
#slider-image-3:target ~ .image-holder {
left: -1600px;
}
</style>
<div class="slider-holder" style="background: yellow; height: 400px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 0px; overflow: hidden; text-align: center; width: 560px" align="center">
    <span id="slider-image-1"></span>
    <span id="slider-image-2"></span>
    <span id="slider-image-3"></span>
    <div class="image-holder" style="-moz-transition: left 2s; -o-transition: left 2s; -webkit-transition: left 2s; background: black; clear: both; height: 400px; position: relative; transition: left 2s; width: 2400px">
        <img src="rsz_test.jpg" class="slider-image" style="float: left; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: relative" align="left">
        <img src="rsz_1test.jpg" class="slider-image" style="float: left; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: relative" align="left">
        <img src="rsz_test.jpg" class="slider-image" style="float: left; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: relative" align="left">
    </div>
    <div class="button-holder" style="position: relative; top: -20px">
        <a href="#slider-image-1" class="slider-change" style="background: brown; border-radius: 5px; display: inline-block; height: 10px; width: 10px"></a>
        <a href="#slider-image-2" class="slider-change" style="background: brown; border-radius: 5px; display: inline-block; height: 10px; width: 10px"></a>
        <a href="#slider-image-3" class="slider-change" style="background: brown; border-radius: 5px; display: inline-block; height: 10px; width: 10px"></a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```